# Unable to connect .net SignalR Server application from android signalR Client application

Tags: android, asp.net-core, signalr, signalr.client

I have .net winform **signalR** Server application ,Which i am able to connect in .net SignalR client application.But in android i am unable to connect SignalR Server application via the URL.In **android signalR client application** is not able to connect to the Server.So how can we resolve this issue. Please find below code

**SignalR android client program**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

public static final int MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE = 123;
public static final int MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_CAMERA = 124;
public static final int MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_LOCATION = 125;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


    ShowPermissionsDialog(this);

    StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new
            StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build();
    StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);

    //http://localhost:8080/signalr/signalr/


    String url="http://10.0.2.2:9999/signalr";
    HubConnection hubConnection = (HubConnection) HubConnectionBuilder.create(url).build();
    TextView textView = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.tvMain);
    ListView listView = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.lvMessages);
    Button sendButton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.bSend);
    EditText editText = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.etMessageText);

    List<String> messageList = new ArrayList<String>();
    ArrayAdapter<String> arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(MainActivity.this,
            android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, messageList);
    listView.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);

    hubConnection.on("Send", (message)-> {
        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                arrayAdapter.add(message);
                arrayAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
        });
    }, String.class);

    sendButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            String message = editText.getText().toString();
            editText.setText("");
            try {
                hubConnection.send("Send", message);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    });

    new HubConnectionTask().execute(hubConnection);
}

class HubConnectionTask extends AsyncTask<HubConnection, Void, Void> {

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
    }

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(HubConnection... hubConnections) {
        try {
            HubConnection hubConnection = hubConnections[0];
            hubConnection.start().blockingAwait();
        }
        catch(Exception exc)
        {
            String msg= exc.getMessage();
            String s=msg;
        }
        return null;
    }
}

private boolean ShowPermissionsDialog(Context context)
{
    if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(context, Manifest.permission.INTERNET) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        if (ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale((Activity) context, Manifest.permission.INTERNET)) {
            AlertDialog.Builder alertBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(context);
            alertBuilder.setCancelable(true);
            alertBuilder.setTitle("Permission necessary");
            alertBuilder.setMessage("External storage permission is necessary");
            alertBuilder.setPositiveButton(android.R.string.yes, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener()
            {

                @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN)
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which)
                {

                    ActivityCompat.requestPermissions((Activity) context, new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE,Manifest.permission.INTERNET,Manifest.permission.CAMERA,Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION,Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION,Manifest.permission.CALL_PHONE,Manifest.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE,Manifest.permission.VIBRATE,Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE,Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE,Manifest.permission.CAMERA}, MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE);

                }
            });

            AlertDialog alert = alertBuilder.create();
            alert.show();
        } else {
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions((Activity) context, new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE, Manifest.permission.INTERNET, Manifest.permission.CAMERA, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION, Manifest.permission.CALL_PHONE, Manifest.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE, Manifest.permission.VIBRATE, Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE, Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE,Manifest.permission.CAMERA}, MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE);
        }

        return false;}
    else {
        return true;
    }
}
```

}

**SignalR Winform Server Application**

[image]

```
 public partial class FrmServer : Form
{
    private IDisposable _signalR;
    private BindingList<ClientItem> _clients = new BindingList<ClientItem>();
    private BindingList<string> _groups = new BindingList<string>();

    public FrmServer()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        bindListsToControls();

        //Register to static hub events
        SimpleHub.ClientConnected += SimpleHub_ClientConnected;
        SimpleHub.ClientDisconnected += SimpleHub_ClientDisconnected;
        SimpleHub.ClientNameChanged += SimpleHub_ClientNameChanged;
        SimpleHub.ClientJoinedToGroup += SimpleHub_ClientJoinedToGroup;
        SimpleHub.ClientLeftGroup += SimpleHub_ClientLeftGroup;
        SimpleHub.MessageReceived += SimpleHub_MessageReceived;
    }

    private void bindListsToControls()
    {
        //Clients list
        cmbClients.DisplayMember = "Name";
        cmbClients.ValueMember = "Id";
        cmbClients.DataSource = _clients;

        //Groups list
        cmbGroups.DataSource = _groups;
    }

    private void SimpleHub_ClientConnected(string clientId)
    {
        //Add client to our clients list
        this.BeginInvoke(new Action(() => _clients.Add(new ClientItem() { Id = clientId, Name = clientId })));

        writeToLog($"Client connected:{clientId}");
    }

    private void SimpleHub_ClientDisconnected(string clientId)
    {
        //Remove client from the list
        this.BeginInvoke(new Action(() =>
        {
            var client = _clients.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Id == clientId);
            if (client != null)
                _clients.Remove(client);
        }));

        writeToLog($"Client disconnected:{clientId}");
    }

    private void SimpleHub_ClientNameChanged(string clientId, string newName)
    {
        //Update the client's name if it exists
        this.BeginInvoke(new Action(() =>
        {
            var client = _clients.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Id == clientId);
            if (client != null)
                client.Name = newName;
        }));

        writeToLog($"Client name changed. Id:{clientId}, Name:{newName}");
    }

    private void SimpleHub_ClientJoinedToGroup(string clientId, string groupName)
    {
        //Only add the groups name to our groups list
        this.BeginInvoke(new Action(() =>
        {
            var group = _groups.FirstOrDefault(x => x == groupName);
            if (group == null)
                _groups.Add(groupName);
        }));

        writeToLog($"Client joined to group. Id:{clientId}, Group:{groupName}");
    }

    private void SimpleHub_ClientLeftGroup(string clientId, string groupName)
    {
        writeToLog($"Client left group. Id:{clientId}, Group:{groupName}");
    }

    private void SimpleHub_MessageReceived(string senderClientId, string message)
    {
        //One of the clients sent a message, log it
        this.BeginInvoke(new Action(() =>
        {
            string clientName = _clients.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Id == senderClientId)?.Name;

            writeToLog($"{clientName}:{message}");
        }));
    }

    private void btnStartServer_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        txtLog.Clear();

        try
        {
            //Start SignalR server with the give URL address
            //Final server address will be "URL/signalr"
            //Startup.Configuration is called automatically
            _signalR = WebApp.Start<Startup>(txtUrl.Text);

            btnStartServer.Enabled = false;
            txtUrl.Enabled = false;
            btnStop.Enabled = true;
            grpBroadcast.Enabled = true;

            writeToLog($"Server started at:{txtUrl.Text}");
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
        }
    }

    private void btnStop_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        _clients.Clear();
        _groups.Clear();

        SimpleHub.ClearState();

        if (_signalR != null)
        {
            _signalR.Dispose();
            _signalR = null;

            btnStop.Enabled = false;
            btnStartServer.Enabled = true;
            txtUrl.Enabled = true;
            grpBroadcast.Enabled = false;

            writeToLog("Server stopped.");
        }
    }

    private void btnSend_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var hubContext = GlobalHost.ConnectionManager.GetHubContext<SimpleHub>();

        if (rdToAll.Checked)
        {
            hubContext.Clients.All.addMessage("SERVER", txtMessage.Text);
        }
        else if (rdToGroup.Checked)
        {
            hubContext.Clients.Group(cmbGroups.Text).addMessage("SERVER", txtMessage.Text);
        }
        else if (rdToClient.Checked)
        {
            hubContext.Clients.Client((string)cmbClients.SelectedValue).addMessage("SERVER", txtMessage.Text);
        }
    }

    private void writeToLog(string log)
    {
        if (this.InvokeRequired)
            this.BeginInvoke(new Action(() => txtLog.AppendText(log + Environment.NewLine)));
        else
            txtLog.AppendText(log + Environment.NewLine);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

when you need to connect from outside "localhost", set in file "appsettings.json" below "endpoints", set "url" to "http://0.0.0.0:9999".

Comment: Please epxlain how this works and why you think it helps.